# jQuery addClass in external js file issue

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <link href="css/colorcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/sample.js"></script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnSample" value="click me" />
        <label id="lblAll">All Toggle</label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lblAll").addClass("defaultColor");
});

$("body").on("click", "#lblAll", function () {
    $("#lblAll").toggleClass("dummy");
});
```

css:

```
.dummy {
     background: yellow;
}
.defaultColor {
background-color: aliceblue;
 }
```

The question is, the above code is not working. I'm trying to use addClass where the js is written in some external js file. Same script, if I put under the body it works fine. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Please check external script is loading or not.

Comment: you should wrap all the code in document ready ... you are only warping the first part :)

Answer (score 1):

That is because `.defaultColor` which is present in the css after dummy always overrides the color applied by `.dummy` as it appears earlier than `.defaultColor`. So if you switch the order of how the css rules are placed it should work fine. This is just a matter of Css Specificity.

See this order, so that `.dummy` if present, will override `.defaultColor` successfully.

```
   .defaultColor {
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }

    .dummy {
      background: yellow;
   }
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A34ex/)

Some reads on css specifity.

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1):

[**1**]. use `!important` in your css class `.dummy`

This way:

```
.dummy {
    background: yellow !important; /*<---here*/
}
.defaultColor {
    background-color: aliceblue;
 }
```

[**Find in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bDH5F/)

---

[**2**]. Or you can move the `.dummy` down below to the `.defaultColor`:

This way:

```
.defaultColor {
    background-color: aliceblue;
 }
.dummy {
    background: yellow; 
}
```

Comment: Both worked.. Confused!!! How come this happens?? I can write css class anywhere right?

Comment: because `.defaultColor` appears after dummy it overwrites the style it never color it yellow defined in the `.dummy`, so if this happens then we have to use `!important` as suggested in the first example it gets the higher priority if class is added to the element other wise write the class below the default one.

Comment: but I'm putting them in the external css class right? external css class, I can define anywhere right? Like OOP concept?

Comment: Yup but to understand styling is that the css class comes later would have higher priority thats why we have to follow a stacking order like this in the second option other wise we have to use `! important`

Answer (score 0):

please apply this code first of all delete the old class

like this

```
$("body").on("click", "#lblAll", function () {
    $("#lblAll").removeClass("defaultColor").toggleClass("dummy");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think, you have written your code `2 times` so it `executes` 2 times **first** which is written in `scripts/sample.js`.

And the **second** one is in your page. 
Removing the code from any one side may solve your issue.

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/dSXPE/1/

```
Also check if I wrote the code 2 times then what will happen
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/dSXPE/2/